# Java Objects with Struts Drop down

Tags: struts2

I am using Strust2 for the presentation layer.I have struts form with drop down which binds with the java object(Application) list.
Drop down displays application object list, user can select one Application and submit.When retrieve the user input value in the Action class, receiving value type is "String", Can't we retrieve objects directly from the struts drop down,In my case "Application" objects

```
   private List<Application> applicaionList = new ArrayList<Application>();
   @Autowired
   private ApplicationService applicationService;
   private Application application;

   public void loadTheForm(){
       applicationList = applicationService.findAll();
   }

   public void submitForm(){
       Document doc = new Document();
       doc.setApplication(application);

   }
   //Getter Setters...
```

}

application.jsp

```
<s:form action ="submitForm">
    <s:select list ="applicationList" headerValue="---Select---" headerKey="-1" name="application"/>
</s:form>
```

struts.xml

```
   <action name="submitForm" class="com.ActionSupport" method="submitForm">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">/newAdminDocumentRequired.tiles</result>
   </action>
```

When user select the value from the drop down and submit, the submitted value is string,
Can't we take the object directly in Struts, if we can't how we can get the object of the selected value?

Thank you,
Udeshika

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? I'm not able to understand what you want.

Comment: I have changed it now,I want to know that can't we get the direct object using struts2?

Comment: ok, I have added the part of the struts.xml , I'm not using execute() method here

Comment: I could be tired but I'm still missing the point. Please explain what you want in a paragraph. Particularly what "the object" is when you say "... take the object directly in Struts...". Taking a guess you are sending a value from your drop down to an action and what then you want that value to assume a type other than String?

Comment: You have a user defined class called com.ActionSupport?

Comment: We will probably need to see the class for Application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I got from your question is

```
 1. You have to show list of applications as drop-down.
 2. User selects one application and submit the form.
 3. You have to retrieve the selected application and perform some action with it.
```

I assume your Application class has a property 'id' which is unique to all applications. And a applicationName, which you have to show to the users.
     So now, I would have solved this issue as follows

```
  <s:form action ="submitForm">
        <s:select list ="applicationList" headerValue="---Select---" headerKey="-1" key="application" listKey="id" listValue="applicationName"/>
    </s:form>
```

Now, this tag will create a drop-down like follows

```
<select name="application">
    <option value="-1" selected="selected">---Select---</option>
    <option value="1">Demo 1 App</option>
    <option value="2">Demo 2 App</option>
    <option value="3">Demo 3 App</option>
    <option value="4">Demo 4 App</option> 
   </select>
```

Note that values(1,2,3,4) in OPTION elements are application.id and titles(Demo 1 App, Demo 2 App,etc) are application.applicationName.

Now, user will select and submit. The id of selected application will be sent to struts action in parameter "application". 
   In Action, you can do this

```
public MyClass extends ActionSupport{

   private List<Application> applicaionList = new ArrayList<Application>();
   @Autowired
   private ApplicationService applicationService;
   private **String** application;

   public void loadTheForm(){
       applicationList = applicationService.findAll();
   }

   public void submitForm(){
       Application varApp = applicationService.findApplicationById(getApplication());
       Document doc = new Document();
       doc.setApplication(varApp);

   }
   //Getter Setters...

}
```

Please note that I have changed type of application to String. And yes, I don't think you can pass directly object from drop-down.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, I wanted to know that , so we can't pass objects directly to the from the drop down, Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dropdown with object attributes 
Here Example is shown for store object
```

//Store Bean class

```
calss Store{
private int storeId;
private String storeName;

//getter setter

}
```

//Action Class
//Set the list in struts2 action class (Model Driven)

```
List<Store> storeList=new ArrayList<>();
```

//JSP page

```
<s:select id="store" name="store" headerKey="-1"
                                headerValue="Select Store " list="storeList"
                                listKey="storeId" listValue="storeId"
                                value="%{IteratorList[#status.index].itemBase.{storeId}}"
                            /></td>
```